# How to make validation check before sending request to server in android?

Tags: android

I have an app which contain mobile number ,pass,and email ,scenario is something like that if user enter email id like"lll" and press submit button then app will send value like "lll" to server ,but what I want condition will only check only if user enter some thing in email edit text ,if user does not enter any thing then app should send request to server with only mobile and password becuse email is optionel.How can I do that

code:-

```
@Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        m_Email = m_EmailEditText.getText().toString().trim();
                        if (!isValidEmail(m_Email)) {
                            CSnackBar.getInstance().showSnackBarError(findViewById(R.id.mainLayout), "Please enter valid Email Id", getApplicationContext());

                        } else {
                            confirmationDialog();//open confirmation dialog.....
                        }

                    }
                });
    /*validation for email*/
private boolean isValidEmail(String email) {// validation for email Id
    String emailPattern = "^[_A-Za-z0-9-\\+]+(\\.[_A-Za-z0-9-]+)*@"
            + "[A-Za-z0-9-]+(\\.[A-Za-z0-9]+)*(\\.[A-Za-z]{2,})$";

    Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(emailPattern);
    Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(email);
    return matcher.matches();
}
```

Comment: please Check this link and use Saripar
https://github.com/ragunathjawahar/android-saripaar

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had faced similar issue and i had prepared a module for checking it .
I had prepared a code for all type of checking say name,phonenumber,emailid,enrollment number etc .

this is Validation.java class where we had defined all type of checking :-

```
package com.Validation;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.EditText;

import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

public class Validation {

    // Regular Expression
    // you can change the expression based on your need
    private static final String EMAIL_REGEX = "^[_A-Za-z0-9-\\+]+(\\.[_A-Za-z0-9-]+)*@[A-Za-z0-9-]+(\\.[A-Za-z0-9]+)*(\\.[A-Za-z]{2,})$";
    private static final String PHONE_REGEX = "\\d{3}-\\d{7}";
    public static final String USERNAME_PATTERN =  "^[a-z0-9_-]{3,15}$";

    private static Matcher matcher;
    private static Pattern pattern;
   /// private static final String USERNAME_PATTERN =;
    // Error Messages
    private static final String REQUIRED_MSG = "required";
    private static final String EMAIL_MSG = "invalid email";
    private static final String PHONE_MSG = "###-#######";
////for user name validation

    public Validation(){

        pattern = Pattern.compile(Validation.USERNAME_PATTERN);
    }

    public static boolean validateusername(String username){

        matcher = pattern.matcher(username);
        return matcher.matches();

    }

    // call this method when you need to check email validation
    public static boolean isEmailAddress(EditText editText, boolean required) {
        return isValid(editText, EMAIL_REGEX, EMAIL_MSG, required);
    }

    // call this method when you need to check phone number validation
    public static boolean isPhoneNumber(EditText editText, boolean required) {


        return isValid(editText, PHONE_REGEX, PHONE_MSG, required);
    }

    // return true if the input field is valid, based on the parameter passed
    public static boolean isValid(EditText editText, String regex, String errMsg, boolean required) {

        String text = editText.getText().toString().trim();



        editText.setError(null);

        // text required and editText is blank, so return false
        if ( required && !hasText(editText) ) return false;

        // pattern doesn't match so returning false
        if (required && !Pattern.matches(regex, text)) {

            editText.setError(errMsg);
            return false;
        };

        return true;
    }

    // check the input field has any text or not
    // return true if it contains text otherwise false
    public static boolean hasText(EditText editText) {

        String text = editText.getText().toString().trim();
        editText.setError(null);

        // length 0 means there is no text
        if (text.length() == 0) {
            editText.setError(REQUIRED_MSG);
            return false;
        }

        return true;
    }
}
```

Now in your activity where you want to put validation please put code like :-

```
public class MyActivity extends Activity {

    private EditText etNormalText;
     private EditText etEmailAddrss;
    private EditText etPhoneNumber;
    private Button btnSubmit;
    public static final String USERNAME_PATTERN =  "^[a-z_-]{1,15}$";
    public static final String ENUM_PATTERN =  "^[a-z0-9_-]{3,12}$";

    private static Matcher matcher;
    private static Pattern pattern,patforeno;


    public MyActivity(){

        pattern = Pattern.compile(USERNAME_PATTERN);
        patforeno = Pattern.compile(ENUM_PATTERN);

    }


    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_my);

        registerViews();
    }

    public static boolean validateusername(String username){

        matcher = pattern.matcher(username);
        return matcher.matches();

    }
    private void registerViews() {
        etNormalText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.et_normal_text);
        // TextWatcher would let us check validation error on the fly
        etNormalText.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
                //Validation.hasText(etNormalText);


            }
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after){}
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count){}
        });

        etEmailAddrss = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.et_email_address);
        etEmailAddrss.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
            // after every change has been made to this editText, we would like to check validity
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
                Validation.isEmailAddress(etEmailAddrss, true);
            }
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after){}
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count){}
        });

        etPhoneNumber = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.et_phone_number);
        etPhoneNumber.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {


                    Validation.isPhoneNumber(etPhoneNumber, false);

            }
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after){}
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count){}
        });

        btnSubmit = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_submit);
        btnSubmit.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                /*
                Validation class will check the error and display the error on respective fields
                but it won't resist the form submission, so we need to check again before submit
                 */
                if (checkValidation())
                    submitForm();
                else
                    Toast.makeText(MyActivity.this, "Form contains error", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        });
    }

    private void submitForm() {
        // Submit your form here. your form is valid
        etNormalText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.et_normal_text);
        boolean isvalidu = false;
        etPhoneNumber = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.et_phone_number);
        etEmailAddrss = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.et_email_address);
        ////email validation


        if (Validation.isEmailAddress(etEmailAddrss, true)) {

            Log.d("mail", "validmail");

        } else {
            Log.d("mail", "invalidvalidmail");
        }

        ///phone number validation
        int length = etPhoneNumber.getText().toString().length();
        Log.d("length", String.valueOf(length));
        int ten = 10;
        if (length != ten) {
Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Please enter your ten digit mobile number",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        } else {
            Validation.isPhoneNumber(etPhoneNumber, false);
            Log.d("numberpho","valid");
        }
        ///username validation
        try {
          isvalidu=validateusername(etNormalText.getText().toString());
            Log.d("hello valid username", "error message"+isvalidu);
            Toast.makeText(this, "Submitting form..."+isvalidu, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.d("hello valid username", "error message"+isvalidu);
            Toast.makeText(this, "Submitting form...", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }

    private boolean checkValidation() {
        boolean ret = true;

        if (!Validation.hasText(etNormalText)) ret = false;
        if (!Validation.isEmailAddress(etEmailAddrss, true)) ret = false;
        if (!Validation.isPhoneNumber(etPhoneNumber, false)) ret = false;

        return ret;
    }
}
```

So hope these will help for your code , actually you must just refine my code according to your requirments.registerView() and checkValidation() and submitforms() methods are considerable for validation .

Answer (score 1):

You can check email is empty or not.
If email is not empty -> validate email
If email is empty -> do nothing

```
public void onClick(View v) {
        m_Email = m_EmailEditText.getText().toString().trim();
        if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(m_Email)) { // check m_Email is not empty
            // m_Email is not empty
            if (!isValidEmail(m_Email)) {
                CSnackBar.getInstance().showSnackBarError(findViewById(R.id.mainLayout), "Please enter valid Email Id", getApplicationContext());
            } else {
                confirmationDialog(); //open confirmation dialog.....
            }
        }
        ...
}
```

Comment: I want to only check with codition when user enter somethisng in email id edit text if not enetered anything then no need to check with the codition

Answer (score 0):

Here is what I do

```
if (email.contains("@") ){
    if ( email.charAt(email.length-3)=='.' || email.charAt(email.length-4) == '.'){
    //do stuff
    }}
    else Toast.makeText(this , "Email is not valid" , Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show;
```

this makes sure that email is like something@something.xxx or .xx 
as there are too many domains and I think there are 2 or 3 characters in it
you can edit accordingly but it works

Answer (score 0):

Use this function to check mail is in format or not:

```
public final static boolean isValidEmail(CharSequence target) {
        if (target == null) {
            return false;
        } else {
            return android.util.Patterns.EMAIL_ADDRESS.matcher(target).matches();
        }
    }
```

Then use your method.

> p.s. Here i'm using default matcher for email address.So there is no
>   need to create our own matchers.

Comment: I want to check with validation only if email is entered if not entered email then no need to check

Comment: Ok then just use Textutil.isEmpty